# Function graph with dplyr

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I would to create a function with a graph

My dataset is like that :

```
Age   NAP
17    0,282
18    0,8282
19    0,223
```

age is the variable Var in function

```
plot_stats_freq_continu <- function(df,  Var , y = NAP)
{

  df$sinistres <- rep(1,nrow(df))
  data_graph <- df %>% 
    group_by(!! Var)%>%
    summarise(Annee_police = sum(NAP), Nb_sinistres= sum(sinistres)) %>%  
    mutate(Fréquence = mean((Nb_sinistres/Annee_police)))     

  ndata_graph <-  as.data.frame(data_graph)
  p <- ggplot(data=data_graph, aes(x=Var)) +geom_density() +geom_point(data=data_graph, aes(x=Var, y= Fréquence))
  plot(p)
}
```

This is my function, it's walk when I try my code without function but it's not ok with function,

I have the following error :

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (23): x

Comment: can you provide some data to easily test your function.

Comment: Duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057452/aesthetics-must-either-be-length-one-or-the-same-length-as-the-dataproblems)?

Comment: @Jimbou Yes!! sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
plot_stats_freq_continu <- function(df,  Var){
  Var <- enquo(Var)
   df %>% 
    mutate(sinistres = 1) %>% 
    group_by(!!Var) %>%
    summarise(Annee_police = sum(NAP), Nb_sinistres= sum(sinistres)) %>%  
    mutate(Fréquence = mean((Nb_sinistres/Annee_police))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes_q(Var)) + 
    geom_density()+
    geom_point(aes_q(Var, quote(Fréquence)))
}

plot_stats_freq_continu(d, Age)
```

[image]

The problem was that the `Var` was not recognized by ggplot. Using `substitute` solves this issue.

Comment: @Naï Edited my answer to use piping until the end. If you`re happy with it, please consider to accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with your data. I ran your code on the data you have provided (but i removed the `,` from the numbers) and your code worked fine. Unless you provide example data and a reproducible example we can not help you.

I am going to guess it has something to do with this chunk:

```
  data_graph <- df %>% 
    group_by(!! Var)%>%
    summarise(Annee_police = sum(NAP), Nb_sinistres= sum(sinistres)) %>%  
    mutate(Fréquence = mean((Nb_sinistres/Annee_police)))
```

The computation in the above code is probably producing `Fréquence` that is shorter than your data (which the error states is 23). I'm going to guess this code is silently erroring out and producing an empty data.frame. Also this line:

`ndata_graph <-  as.data.frame(data_graph)`

is either redundant/unused.