# How do ggplot and dplyr select unquoted variables in function

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Within `ggplot2` and `dplyr`, functions do not require the column name of the variable to be quoted. Here are some examples:

```
# A plot example
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_point()


# A dplyr example
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl)
```

However, if we try and directly replicate this in a function, it will complain that the unqouted object cannot be found:

```
foo <- function(df, x){
   df %>%
    select(x)    
}

foo(mtcars, cyl)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'cyl' not found

**How can the behaviour of these packages be replicated within my own functions, so that adding unquoted variables does not result in the above error?**

---

I know we can use the underscore version of functions in dplyr to use character strings, or `aes_string()` within `ggplot`. For example:

```
foo2 <- function(df, x){    
  df %>%
    select_(x)      
}

foo(mtcars, "cyl")
```

I was hoping to find a solution which is consistent with the way it is done in these packages. I have looked a bit through the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr), but it has only added to the confusion.

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645557/function-graph-with-dplyr/49646363#49646363

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use quosures to achieve this. See [this](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) excellent article for more info on how it works and how to use it

```
foo <- function(df, x){

    x <- enquo(x)

    df %>%
      select(!!x)    
}
```

Comment: Maybe more intuitive to read would be to replace enquo() with substitute() from base r.